# Cauchy Principal value: Question about the integration boundaries of this integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$\int\limits_{C_1}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} \ dz$$
in the limit $r\to0$. $C_1$ is a semi circle with radius $r$ in the complex plane ($z=re^{i\theta},0<\theta<\pi$).

Going through the textbook solution it says:
$$\int\limits_{C_1}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} \ dz=\int\limits_{\pi}^{0}\frac{1-e^{ire^{i\theta}}}{r^2e^{2i\theta}}ire^{i\theta} \ d\theta=\ ...$$

I honestly don't know why the integration would go from $\pi$ to $0$ and not the other way around?
I think this should have something to do with the direction I'm going  around $C_1$ (my integration path) but I'm not sure how to argue this the correct way.

Any help would be really appriciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the direction you traverse the semicircle in. Presumably $C_1$ is part of a closed contour consisting of two intervals, $[-R, -r]$ and $[r,R]$, $C_1$, and a large semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane, that is traversed in the positive sense. And that means you traverse $C_1$ from $-r$ ($\theta = \pi$) to $r$ ($\theta = 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 1: Using
$$ e^z-1=z+\frac12z^2+\cdots $$
then you can get
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{C_1}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} \ dz\\
&=&-\int_{C_1}\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2} \ dz\\
&=&-\int_{C_1}\bigg(\frac{i}{z}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac1{3!}iz+\cdots\bigg) \ dz.
\end{eqnarray}
It is easy to see
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac1{3!}zi+\cdots\bigg) \ dz=0 $$
and
$$ \int_{C_1}\frac{i}{z}\ dz=\int_0^\pi\frac{i}{re^{i\theta}}ir^{i\theta}d\theta=-\pi.
$$
So
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int\limits_{C_1}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} \ dz=\pi. $$
Update 2: You also can use the Cauchy formula. Since $C_1$ is the half unit circle, you have
$$ \int_{C_1}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} \ dz=\frac12\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} \ dz=\frac12\cdot2\pi i\text{Res}(\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2},z=0)=\pi.$$

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for answering! I‘m little bit confused how this identity is linked to the boundaries of the integral? Doesn‘t that only help me in actual computing the integral? (Cause I can write  $1-e^{z}$ as an infinite series...)

Comment: Yes, you can. Just use this and then take limit.